# Directive Fails to fire when scope changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an app which displays content from reddit and using their api to get img urls. Not every post to reddit contains an image however; therefore, I've written a directive to remove any images (and their parent container) that encounter an error when they attempt to bind (either because they're non-images or because they 404).

That directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('img', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                element.error(function() { 
                element.parent().remove(); 
            });         

            scope.$watch(function() { return element['img']; },
                function() { 
                    element.error( 
                        function(){ element.parent().remove(); } 
                    ); 
                }
            );          
        }
    }
});
```

When I first load the page, everything works perfectly. All the images are filtered correctly and the remaining ones fall into place. However, when I reach the bottom of the page ng-infinite-scroll invokes a function to load more images from reddit. These new images are not filtered by the directive and—worse yet—the non-images from the first set come back.

I included the scope.$watch statement in hopes of resolving this issue but it didn't seem to help.

Any ideas for wrangling with this directive? Thanks!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle to demo the issue please?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom and more images will load; yet, the ones already filtered-out will re-appear as broken images. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogzNZM?editors=101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different approach with only adding the images to the array if they are valid images instead of removing them afterwards. One of the problems is, that a lot of the urls are html pages and not raw images. Some images are also very big so this leads to performance issues ([**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/mgwer/pen/GgjROa)).

```
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
    var items = data.data.children;
    var allPromises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(!items[i].data.url.match(/.+\.(jpg|jpeg||png|gif)$/i)) continue;

        var deferred = $q.defer(); 

        (function(self, index, d) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = items[index].data.url;

            img.onload = function() {
                d.resolve(items[index].data);
            }

            img.onerror = function() {
                d.resolve();
            }
        })(this, i, deferred);

        allPromises.push(deferred.promise);
    }

    $q.all(allPromises).then(function(items) {
        this.items = this.items.concat(items.filter(function(item) {
            return item != undefined;
        }));

        this.after = "t3_" + this.items[this.items.length - 1].id;
        this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));

}.bind(this));
```